# NestJS Swagger OpenAPI CLI Plugin - Exclude Certain Properties

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I love how the CLI plugin prevents me from having to write @ApiProperty() on everything.

However, in some of my entities, while I want MOST properties to be @ApiProperty(), I want some not to be.

I cannot find anything in the documentation that would allow me to EXCLUDE specific fields from automatically receiving @ApiProperty().

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly add `@ApiHideProperty()` and the CLI won't add the `@ApiProperty()` decorator to it.

Comment: Huh... thanks Jay. So, that is hiding the property from the schema output... but if I GET the object by ID, all the hidden properties are still being returned. Is that to be expected?!

Comment: To exclude the property from the response you'd need to follow the [serialization docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) and use `@Exclude()` from `class-transformer`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I am understanding more about Nest now.